# Sorting a list of strings in python on regex isnt actually sorted

Tags: python, sorting

So i have a list of strings and im sorting it with:

```
list = [' R1O-GN | ile: 13 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 6 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 11 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 9 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 11 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 9 |', ' J-ZYSZ | ile: 12 |', ' UGR-J2 | ile: 8 |']

def ile_sort(elem):
    return re.findall(r'ile: (\d+)',elem)

list = sorted(list, key=ile_sort)
```

String with 6 should be first and one with 13 last, but the actual result is:

```
[' LXQ2-T | ile: 11 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 11 |', ' J-ZYSZ | ile: 12 |', ' R1O-GN | ile: 13 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 6 |', ' UGR-J2 | ile: 8 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 9 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 9 |']
```

Comment: they sort key should be a returning a single element part from the list. the `findall` returns a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that using `re.findall()` on those list items returns a string within a list, such as this: `["13"]`

To combat this, replace your `ile_sort()` method with this:

```py
def ile_sort(elem):
    return int(re.findall('ile: (\d+)', elem)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was sorting based on strings not integers so thats why its 11, 12, 2

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, you need to return a single element from the function that has been passed to the `key` parameter. (not a list which is returned from `findall`). That element is going to be used for sorting.

You can get the first item from the `findall` or change `findall` to `search` and grab the first *group*. Don't forget to convert the final result to integer.

```py
import re

lst = [' R1O-GN | ile: 13 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 6 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 11 |',
       ' LXQ2-T | ile: 9 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 11 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 9 |',
       ' J-ZYSZ | ile: 12 |', ' UGR-J2 | ile: 8 |']

def ile_sort(elem):
    return int(re.search(r'ile: (\d+)', elem).group(1))

lst = sorted(lst, key=ile_sort)
print(lst)
```

output:

```
[' LXQ2-T | ile: 6 |', ' UGR-J2 | ile: 8 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 9 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 9 |', ' LXQ2-T | ile: 11 |', ' 4-HWWF | ile: 11 |', ' J-ZYSZ | ile: 12 |', ' R1O-GN | ile: 13 |']
```